# How to protect a webserver folder while authorizing a Java program to write into it

Tags: java, php, linux, apache, file-permissions

One of my website pages (written in PHP) manipulates a MySQL database before starting a .jar archive in background, with the following command :

```
nohup java -jar myJar.jar > /dev/null &
```

This jar creates a text file in a folder (the current one or subfolders). For my Java program to write file, I have to set the `w` (write) permission to `a` (all users) on the `www` folder (or one of its subfolders).

Based on what I read, one of the solutions would be to give the write permission only to www-data, which would be Apache. Howerver I cannot see how it is more secure than a 777 chmod, because a hacker would always have the permission to write through his browser.

Do you know a solution which would :

- Make my server as safe as possible.
- Allow my Java program (launched by PHP) to create and modify files on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run your java program as a deamon with its own user with a privelege to edit that specific folder.

Set it to monitor a file or database to see if it needs to run and do its thing. Then when your php script needs it just modify the file/database.

Comment: Would it be secure if, instead of modifying a file/database, the PHP script starts the daemon (a service in /etc/init.d ?) the way it is explained here : http://www.source-code.biz/snippets/java/7.htm ?
Or would there also be a security issue ?

Comment: You have to think about permissions. If the deamon is started by the php server it's a child process of the www server user.
If you start the process under it's own user, a hacker which would have access to the wwwserver user, wouldn't be able to penetrate the user layers to the java deamon user by proper security protocols.
That is why you need to start the process on it'sself as a deamon and not a single run process.
It means rewriting most of your java application to run as a deamon until a flag is set. Then you would be the most secure imho.

Comment: OK, so there is very little advantage over another method which would be to start the Java program periodically using a Cron (the program should make sure a unique instance is running at a given time, using a lock file). Indeed, the only way I see to monitor the file is to wake up periodically and check the file, so a Cron seems to be better, right?

Comment: A cron would do also, just make sure its another user process that initiates the cron call than the www pocesses user, like system.